# SendGrid - .ics and .ical will not display Yes/No/Maybe for the events I create

Tags: email, sendgrid, icalendar

I am using a node package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ics) to create a .ics file in my app and sending emails via SendGrid.

When I send myself an email from the app, the generated .ics file (or .ical file) does not give me the option to accept or decline the event.

Here is what is generated in the .ics file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:-//my-app//NONSGML v1.0//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:z-zQqunSG3dA8Av0OvrJG
SUMMARY:one more test
DTSTAMP:20230918T222112Z
DTSTART:20230930T050400Z
DTEND:20230930T071500Z
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:asdfasdfasdfasdf
LOCATION:Suite 107 - 123 Fake Street Fakesville, Ontario
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN=asdf:MAILTO:harry@theorganizer.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=Bob The Builder:mailto:bob@thebuilder.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I have read multiple threads on stack overflow and nothing seems wrong with this file.